# Why does Nana have to eat bananas with their skins on as a condition to use her powers?

Tags: banana-no-nana

In the series, it's mentioned that as a condition of her powers, Nana has to eat a banana with the peel on every day, plus an extra one for every time she uses her power.

Did they ever explain the reasoning behind why she had to do this?

[image]

Comment: To the fapcave!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every character in *Banana no Nana* has a "Risk", some kind of condition they have to fulfill in order to keep using their powers. (Most of which, by some odd coincidence, seem to involve fan service.) Nana's is to eat bananas with the skin on. Her friend Ringo, the one forcefeeding her the banana in the above scene, has to wear a miniskirt in order to keep her leg powers. (This allows us and Nana to see her panties every time she uses her kicking attacks.) The first chapter's villain, in exchange for water powers, has to stay in the bath almost all the time, so she has a pair of thugs who carry her around in a bathtub when she goes out.

The only explanation up to the point I've reached is that these conditions are imposed by God in return for the powers. God also puts limits on the strength of powers, but some people, including Ringo, can break these limits under certain conditions. (Ringo's is getting angry.)

Comment: I haven't seen/read the series but just from your answer it almost as if every Risk is designed purely to allow fan service/provocative scenes ("banana eating", panty shots, girl always bathing in a bathtub)...maybe God is just a real pervert unless you have an example of a Risk that can in no way lead to "fan service"

Comment: @Memor-X That's pretty much it, "God" (i.e. the author, Oniyasu Kakazu) is a real pervert who designed the Risks for max fan service. Non-fan servicey ones might exist; for one thing, there are guys with abilities, who would be no service to the mostly male fans. Also, Hoshi Budou, a ninja maid, has the ability Housework Booster that lets her do housework super-fast; her Risk seems to be that she must serve someone. In Chapter 9 she cleans Nana's ears with Nana's head in her lap, which is only mildly fan servicey.